# Disable Windows taskbar menu for a WPF window

Tags: wpf, winapi, pinvoke, .net-7.0

I need to disable Windows taskbar system menu (when you hover over a window on taskbar):

[image]

I want it either to be not visible or all the items grayed out or click on any item (most important - minimize and restore) to be neutralized

IMPORTANT - the solution must not rely on "normal" WPF wiring e.g. `OnStateChanged` handling and using `WindowState` or `SystemCommands` to restore window state back to desired one. Low level/unmanaged/pinvoke/win32 code is welcome.

Because I am already heavily using those, which works for all use cases except when user uses this Windows taskbar commands. I cannot see a more simple and stable solution to exclude that scenario altogether.

Comment: If you want a window that cannot be minimized by a user, you'll have to remove the `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` window style. I don't know how WPF uses/controls the underlying native window.

Comment: no. I presented a very precise question. I want prevent user from all operations using EXACTLY the Windows taskbar context menu. I still want those operations to be available in different use cases

Comment: Not sure I understand, how do you display this (sys commands) menu exactly? I can see it if I click once in the upper left corner (where the icon is usually displayed), but when I hover over a window in the taskbar (it's corresponding icon), I see the window preview.

Comment: Can you just do `ShowInTaskbar="False"` or do you still need/want it to be in the task bar but just without menu options?

Comment: unfortunately no. the users still want it in the taskbar.

Comment: The context menu does not appear on hover; it appears on right-click. The screenshot you included is also not of that context menu; it's of the context menu that appears when you right-click an application's _title_ bar. So I'm not sure what you mean by "when you hover over a window on taskbar"). Can you please edit your question to clarify what specific feature/context menu you are talking about?

Comment: 1) I changed context to system 2) everyone who uses windows understood what i was talking about no big deal 3) you deprived future users from valuable answer and the accepted answer is a rare gem on SO (especially considering SO quality downfall in past few years).. so.. whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That menu is known as [*Window System Menu*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus#the-window-menu). It can be retrieved by [`GetSystemMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmenu). It returns a handle to a *Menu* object.

After obtaining the menu handle, you can pass it to the [`ModifyMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-modifymenuw) function to modify the menu items inside it. It needs which menu items will be modified. You can give that using the `uPosition` parameter. Either you can give a relative position which is zero-based index or an identifier. The system menu has menu items which have predefined identifiers. They are [`SC_MINIMIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand), [`SC_MAXIMIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand), [`SC_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) etc. You use these identifiers to refer the menu item you want to modify.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private IntPtr _hwnd = IntPtr.Zero; 
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        _hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        IntPtr hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(_hwnd, false);
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(64);
        int[] itemIDs = new int[2] { SC_MAXIMIZE, SC_MINIMIZE };
        foreach (var itemID in itemIDs)
        {
            buffer.Clear();
            GetMenuString(hSystemMenu, itemID, buffer, 64, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            ModifyMenu(hSystemMenu, itemID, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED, 0, buffer.ToString());
        }
    }
    
    private const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
    private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
    private const int MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002;
    private const int MF_ENABLED = 0x00000000;
    private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    private const int MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool ModifyMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetMenuString(IntPtr hMenu, int uIDItem, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int cchMax, int flags);
}
```

However, as you could have noticed, disabling a system menu item removes its functionality from the window completely (such as moving, sizing, minimizing etc.).

If we follow the technique from [the @Anders's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44736463/7141410), we can disable a item when the menu is initialized and enable it when the menu is uninitialized. You can enable the menu items back by reverting the system menu with a call to the `GetSystemMenu` where the second parameter is passed as `true`.

This way, the functionalities of the menu items don't get removed.

Here is the revised code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private IntPtr _hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    private IntPtr _hSystemMenu;
    private int[] _itemIDs = new int[] { SC_MAXIMIZE, SC_MINIMIZE, SC_RESTORE, SC_CLOSE, SC_MOVE, SC_SIZE };
    private StringBuilder _buffer = new StringBuilder(64);;
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        _hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        _hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(_hwnd, false); 
        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if(msg == WM_INITMENU)
        {
            foreach (var itemID in _itemIDs)
            {
                _buffer.Clear();
                GetMenuString(_hSystemMenu, itemID, _buffer, 64, MF_BYCOMMAND);
                ModifyMenu(_hSystemMenu, itemID, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED, 0, _buffer.ToString());
            } 
        }
        else if(msg == WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP)
        {
            GetSystemMenu(_hwnd, true);    
            _hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(_hwnd, false);
        }
        handled = false;
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    } 
    private const int WM_INITMENU = 0x0116;
    private const int WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP = 0x0125; 
    private const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
    private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
    private const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;
    private const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    private const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
    private const int SC_SIZE = 0xF000;
    private const int MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002;
    private const int MF_ENABLED = 0x00000000;
    private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    private const int MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001; 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);  
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ModifyMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, int uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetMenuString(IntPtr hMenu, int uIDItem, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int cchMax, int flags);
}
```

Comment: you rock. there very few of you are left on SO. please dont quit!